# How to transfer data one frame to another in netbean

Tags: java

i have write  some cods for GPS in different fame in netbean below run  method continue update 500ms and get new value of longitude and latitude i want to send this value in another class fame how do i it?  target variable is tlon and tlat.t getvalue method not working.

```
public void run() {
            try {
                p1 = new communication().com();
            } catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(vpsmain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(vpsmain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (TooManyListenersException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(vpsmain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }


                  if(p1.substring(0, 1).equals("$"))
                  {
                     s=p1.split("\\$",0);
                      a1=s[1].split("\\*", 0);
                      t=a1[0].split(",",0);
           if((a1[0].substring(2, 5).equalsIgnoreCase("GGA")))
           {



    tlon.setText(t[4].substring(0, 3).concat(" ").concat(t[4].substring(4)).concat("'").concat("  ").concat(t[5]));




           double y1=Double.parseDouble(t[2])*180/Math.PI;


    tlat.setText(t[2].substring(0, 2).concat(" ").concat(t[2].substring(3).concat("'").concat("  ").concat(t[3])));

}
```

Comment: do you mean from one JFrame to another?

Comment: In general, you shouldn't do that, you probably want to use multiple JPanes inside one JFrame

Answer (score 0):

Create a public method (with some parameters) in the target `JFrame` and call that method with relevant parameters. And create class variables to grab those values.
in Frame2

```
public void setData(Lan lan,Lon lon){ // you can use any data type for these values as you need
   // there should be lan & lon defined in the class definition too.
   this.lan = lan;
   this.lon = lon;
}
```

Comment: i also try it i parse my longitude and latitude in argument in target method but it take value initial value.

Comment: create class variables to grab that parameters. if you named them same as in parameters (as in above answer), make sure to use this. to set values. Otherwise those values won't be affected to class variables and the parametric values will be erased right after the the method finished running.